# @Html.RenderAction and Action always return "Input string was not in a correct format."

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am really stumped on this one. I have been searching and trying everything I can think of. My Action or RenderAction always returns the error *"Input string was not in a correct format."* I have an MVC 5 page with the following code.

```
 @Html.Action("GetSocialLinks", new { componentPresentation = Model.ComponentPresentation, clientId = 501 })
```

I have also tried

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("GetSocialLinks", new { componentPresentation = Model.ComponentPresentation, clientId = 501 });}
```

the controller action looks like this:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult GetSocialLinks(IComponentPresentation componentPresentation, int clientId)
    {
        // do some code here
        return PartialView("SocialLinks", socialLinks);
    }
```

I have verified the action is called and runs just fine. The call to PartialView runs fine and I can access values after it runs. I have even removed all the HTML from the SocialLinks view to make sure it was not an issue with that HTML. Why can I not get that view inserted? I need to call back to a child action so get more data.

MVC 5 .Net 4.5

Here is a little stack trace

```
 `System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormat(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args) +13914049
System.String.Format(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args) +136
System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.GetPathFromGeneralName(ControllerContext controllerContext, List`1 locations, String name, String controllerName, String areaName, String cacheKey, String[]& searchedLocations) +211
System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.GetPath(ControllerContext controllerContext, String[] locations, String[] areaLocations, String locationsPropertyName, String name, String controllerName, String cacheKeyPrefix, Boolean useCache, String[]& searchedLocations) +958
System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.FindPartialView(ControllerContext controllerContext, String partialViewName, Boolean useCache) +192
System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.Find(Func`2 lookup, Boolean trackSearchedPaths) +174
System.Web.Mvc.PartialViewResult.FindView(ControllerContext context) +85
System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +147`
```

Comment: That error is often the result of using a `DataAnnotation` incorrectly (e.g. `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C")]` is missing closing brace)

Comment: I can't think of where an error like that would be. I am not returning a view with any HTML in it. I even take my model out so I am not passing in a model. So I am basically returning a blank HTML page with no model attached but I still get the error.

Comment: So if you do `@Html.Action("GetSocialLinks")` with `public ActionResult GetSocialLinks()` (no parameters), are you still getting the error?

Comment: Are you able to write a small application that duplicates the error and post the code? [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes. I still get the error.

Comment: Sorry guys I think I have it. It is a issue with the CMS framework I am connecting to and using.